# Understanding Qualified name lookup for namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, language-lawyer

I would like to understand the namespace qualified name lookup. I am trying to leverage the following

> 3.4.3.2.2: For a namespace X and name m, the namespace-qualified lookup set S(X,m) is defined as follows: Let S'(X,m) be the set of all
>   declarations of m in X and the inline namespace set of X (7.3.1). If
>   S'(X,m) is not empty, S(X,m) is S'(X,m); otherwise, S(X,m) is the
>   union of S(N_i,m) for all namespaces N_i nominated by using-directives
>   in X and its inline namespace set.

to provide a fallback mechanism for a name iff it does not exist in the standard namespace. The following program exemplifies what I am envisaging to achieve

```
#include <type_traits>
namespace foo
{
    template<class Ty>
    struct remove_extent
        {
        typedef Ty type;
        };
}
namespace fallback
{
    using namespace std;
}
namespace fallback
{
    using namespace foo;
}
template<typename Ty>
struct Bar
{
    typename fallback::remove_extent<Ty>::type var;
};
int main()
{
   Bar<int[]> var;
}
```

For the first declaration

```
namespace fallback
{
    using namespace std;
}
```

`S'(fallback, remove_extent)` is an empty set so `S(fallback, remove_extent)` is the union of `S(std, remove_extent).`

For the second declaration

```
namespace fallback
{
    using namespace foo;
}
```

`S'(fallback, remove_extent)` is non-empty so `S(fallback, remove_extent) = S'(fallback, remove_extent) = S(std, remove_extent)`

but my compiler thinks otherwise and complains

```
1>source.cpp(21): error C2872: 'remove_extent' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'source.cpp(6) : foo::remove_extent'
1>          or       'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\type_traits(331) : std::remove_extent'
```

So obviously my understanding is wrong. Why does the compiler includes the name `remove_extent` from foo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For the second declaration ... `S'(fallback, remove_extent)` is non-empty

No, it isn't:

```
namespace fallback
{
    using namespace std;
}
```

After this point, `S'(fallback, remove_extent)` is empty, so `S` is `S(std, remove_extent)`.

```
namespace fallback
{
    using namespace foo;
}
```

After this point, `S'(fallback, remove_extent)` is *still* empty (i.e. there's still no declaration of a `remove_extent` *directly in* `fallback`), so `S` is now the union of `S(std, remove_extent)` and `S(foo, remove_extent)`.

```
template<typename Ty>
struct Bar
{
    typename fallback::remove_extent<Ty>::type var;
};
```

When we get to this point, there are two entities named `remove_extent` in `fallback` (one from `std` and one from `foo`, neither declared directly in `fallback`), so the compiler correctly tells you that the name is ambiguous.